# Angular: El archivo no vuelve a cargarse si lo eliminas

Tags: angular

Tengo un método mediante el cual si hago click a un botón, adjunto un archivo antes de ser enviado y éste aparece en una preview. Tengo la opción de eliminarlo, pero si lo elimino y quiero volver a seleccionar el mismo archivo, no me lo adjunta. Sí me adjunta si es otro archivo distinto. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que si selecciono el mismo archivo que he eliminado, me lo vuelva a adjuntar? ¿Puede ser que se esté guardando en algún sitio y haya que forzar para que lo "borre" cuando se hace delete?

Mi component.ts

```
onAddFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var filesAmount = event.target.files.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event: any) => {
          this.imageurls.push({ base64String: event.target.result, });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
      }
    }
  }

deleteImage(i) {
    this.imageurls.splice(i, 1);
  }
```

Mi html

```
<div class="close file-delete" (click)="removeImage(i)" ></div>

<input id="pic" type="file" accept=".gif,.jpg,.png,.jpeg"(change)="onAddFile($event)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes aqui:

```
<input id="pic" type="file" accept=".gif,.jpg,.png,.jpeg"(change)="onAddFile($event)">
```

Un input de tipo file, solamente te llamara a la funcion de **onAddFile** siempre y cuando el archivo se llame diferente, por eso si pones el mismo archivo no hace nada en cambio si pones otro con otro nombre si te hace caso.

Para poder arreglar este error tendras que resetear el valor antes que haga el change.